# What do you call one who has been challenged?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, american-english

How should I refer to one who has been challenged?

One who offers a challenge is a "challenger," but what would be the appropriate term for the person who receives the challenge?

Comment: I don't think "challenged" would be appropriate, by the way.

Comment: an·tag·o·nist -one that contends with or opposes another : adversary, opponent

Comment: Wiktionary gives _challengee_, but I'd want to see it included in OED before I used it in a formal context and without scare quotes.

Comment: If after an exchange of shots, neither party be hit, it is the duty of the second of the challengee to approach the second of the challenger and say: "Our friends have exchanged shots, are you satisfied, or is there any cause why the contest ...    Challengee: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=challengee&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchallengee%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Challengee has about 357,000 google results.

Comment: Often the one being challenged is the champion, leader, pacesetter or alpha-dog.

Comment: @tigertrussell Is there a reason you reject the substantive use of the past participle as an option?

Comment: @ScotM The context in which this word will be used wouldn't lend itself to the word "challenged." I can't go in to detail, sadly (NDA). Edit: thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Competitor? Rival? Contender? Foe? Defendant (as opposed to plaintiff)? Contestant?Opposer? Foe? Withstander? A hostile? Combatant? Defender? Disputant?

All the above are more or less valid as a synonym for a challenger, but that depends, of course, on the larger context in which the word appears. Here are some sentences which provide context:

> - I *challenged* Drake to a duel. He turned out to be a worthy *opponent*.
> - When I *challenged* Demetrius, he told me that under no circumstances would he become my *foe*.
> - My chosen *combatant* did not take kindly to being *challenged*.
> - Knowing Julius was open to being *challenged*, I had no trouble getting him to become a truly formidable *rival* in the competition.
> - I *challenged* the *hostile* after getting the jump on him while reconnoitering the perimeter of the combat zone.

Comment: "Defender" actually works really well for our context. Thank you very much!